# Manually compile dom elements that are composed of other custom elements in aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I am using the approach that Jeremy Danyow specifies in this link:

[How do you use ViewCompiler to manually compile part of the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527389/how-do-you-use-viewcompiler-to-manually-compile-part-of-the-dom)

Here is my code:

```
this.viewFactory.insert(this.viewportEl, '<template><' + name + '></' + name + '></template>', this);
```

which is working fine in the sense that it is replacing the contents of the dom element. However, the dynamic custom element is not getting compiled. I even tried adding a require statement inside the dynamic template and it gets included just fine but the custom element is still not getting compiled.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `globalResources` to ensure the custom element is loaded.

https://gist.run/?id=762c00133d5d5be624f9

Comment: Thanks, yes, I had thought of that. However, I was really hoping to use require instead because these elements really are page-specific and shouldn't be globalized. Is there any way to manually compile and ensure that the custom elements will be recognized?