# Creating elements in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia, aurelia-templating

I'm trying to create an Aurelia element inside of another element. I'm using the docking framework from [phosphor](http://phosphorjs.github.io/) and when I dynamically create a panel I want to add a component which I've build using Aurelia.

For example: I have a very simple logging component:

Logging.html

```
<template>
    <h1>Logging....</h1>
</template>
```

Logging.ts:

```
export class Logging {
    constructor() {
        console.log('Logging constructor')
    }
}
```

The component works as expected when I "just put it on the page".

Now inside of some method which creates the phosphor Widget I have something like this:

```
var widget = new Widget();
widget.title = "Got Logs?";
var contentElement = document.createElement('logging');
widget.node.appendChild(contentElement);
panel.insertBottom(widget);
```

This code, given a phosphor panel, creates a Widget, creates an element which looks like: `<logging></logging>` and appends it to the widget's inner node. The resulting "DOM" is correct but aurelia does not render the element.

I have also tried using the TemplatingEngine like so:

```
import { inject, TemplatingEngine } from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(TemplatingEngine)
export class AureliaRoot {
    constructor(templatingEngine) { }

    attached() {
        var contentElement = document.createElement("logging"),
            el = document.getElementById("my-element");
        el.appendChild(contentElement);
        templatingEngine.enhance({element: el, bindingContext: {}});
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work, although I doubt I'm using it right and I think I might need to use `compile`, really not sure there.

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: It depends at what point this is created, because as far as my knowledge with SPA frameworks goes they will act upon the DOM as is, if you manipulate the DOM outside of this action (which you are most likely doing) then the framework will not know of your changes.

Comment: Indeed, but I'm looking for a way to "force the compilation" of my view.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that i won't be able to answer fully, but i believe you will need to use the Aurelia ViewCompiler to compile the fragments of HTML generated so that they are parsed by Aurelia.

Try looking at the following link for more information: [How do you use ViewCompiler to manually compile part of the DOM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527389/how-do-you-use-viewcompiler-to-manually-compile-part-of-the-dom)

Comment: This seems to be outdated and you should now use the `TemplatingEngine`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i will look into the TemplatingEngine :)